# zsh function export needlesly verbose

Tags: shell, zsh, configuration, console

When I configure a function in `.zshrc`, it is printed to the console one time when I `source .zshrc` (or open a new console window).

.zshrc:

```
function test { echo 'Hellow World'; }
export -f test
```

console output:

```
>> source .zshrc
test () { echo 'Hello World'; }
>>
```

I want to disable this but I couldn't find anywhere how to do it.

Comment: Do you need the export statement there?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that, I get: `invalid option(s)` when I try to do `export -f test`. If you get output that you are not interested in, you can always pipe it to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Why are you trying to export the function? In ZSH 5.4.1 that gives `invalid option(s)` and the docs for `typeset` by way of `export` indicate that your flags are indeed an illegal combination.

Comment: My mistake... I copied the function definition (+export) from the internet without understanding what it does. I thought it was necessary in order to have the function available in the shell. Removing the export line solves my problem. Thank you all!